# Using Previously Calculated Values in a CASE Statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently working on this Oracle database to figure out inactive relationships based on many conditions.

So currently I have a CASE statement to calculate the 'Status' field by using the last login date.

Following are the condition I have to check.

1. Last login date is within 6 months then set the status as Active - This I already did.
2. Last Login date is older than 6 months and if the user has another account/s which has an active status which was calculated in the previous condition, then make the second/multiple account/s Status as Active as well.
   This one I'm unable to achieve.

I tried to select the resultant table in to a FROM clause once again hoping that I can populate the data. but I do not understand how to write that piece.

```
SELECT t1.UserName,
       t1.UserID,
       t1.LastLoginDate,
       t1.status      
  FROM (SELECT UserName,
               UserID,
               LastLoginDate,              
               (CASE
                    WHEN LastLoginDate > ADD_MONTHS ('01-Jul-2019', -6)
                    THEN
                        'Active'
                END)
                   AS status
          FROM User_Mas_Table) t1
```

Above query gives me the following results.

```
UserName    UserID          LastLoginDate   STATUS
----------  ----------  --------------- ------
AAAAAA          1           7/23/2019       Active
AAAAAA          2           7/24/2019       Active
AAAAAA          3           11/7/2018             
CCCCCC          4           7/24/2019       Active
BBBBBB          5           4/30/2019       Active
DDDDDD          6           5/24/2019       Active
EEEEEE          7           7/22/2019       Active
FFFFFF          8           3/14/2019       Active
GGGGGG          9           7/24/2019       Active
GGGGGG          10          5/14/2018             
HHHHHH          11          4/30/2019       Active
```

I need to fill those empty ones as active as well.

Comment: I recommend adding sample data as well (as small a data set as is needed to get your business logic points across).

Comment: I can't put the real data. But I can say the following.
If the user is having more than one account then it means its User Name is same for all the accounts but the user ID differs. Those are the only two values I have to work with. But once I get the second select query I do have the calculated STATUS field as a column in the second table. But I do not know how to count based on the UserName and find the Empty one and fill it.

Comment: It doesn't matter now because Gordon answered (he's usually right), but if you add sample data it would make your question more helpful for others in the future `:-)`

Comment: Gordon's answer IMHO answers your question correctly, though it seems to me the `UserID` column should be actually named `AccountID` (because it doesn't map user bijectively) and status is actually function of user, not account.

Comment: Thank you tim... really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a window function to compare the most recent login date over *all* user accounts:

```
select um.*,
       (case when max(lastlogindate) over (partition by username) > add_months(date '2019-07-01', -6)
             then 'Active'
        end) as status
from User_Mas_Table um;
```

If you only want "active" when the account has a `lastlogindate`, then the logic is:

```
select um.*,
       (case when lastlogindate is not null and
                  max(lastlogindate) over (partition by username) > add_months(date '2019-07-01', -6)
             then 'Active'
        end) as status
from User_Mas_Table um;
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks Gordon. I need to read the usage of those keywords so i can use them effectively.

Comment: I did run this on my full data set.But I ended up with one issue..
There users who don't have the last login date captured and those are marked as active as well..

WHEN (last_tover_date IS NOT NULL
                  AND MAX (last_tover_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ac_short_name)) >
                     ADD_MONTHS ('01-Jul-2019', -6)

Tried the above but it gives me an error.

Comment: @SAMROX . . . I think your parentheses are off.